# cakephp theme not loading on live server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

site url http://mathsmitra.in/

Theme directory location

```
app\View\Themed\Default
```

appcontroller.php

```
public $view   = 'Themed';
public $theme = 'Default';
```

cakephp version 2.4.6

img,css and js not loading in my site and site perfectly working on local server.
How to resolve.

Comment: Are you sure the theme is uploaded to your live server? Are there any errors showing? Check logs/errors.log also

Comment: @CMN and sure files uploaded on server. there no error showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked console there is 404 error message... You have to adjust rights(permissions).

when I started to substitute with for example

**THIS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme/Default/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**WITH THIS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

works as desired... this way you can make it work or just set proper rights

If this doesn't work, try to put css files inside webroot/css/ directory and from page call:

```
echo $this->Html->css('yourcssfilename_withoutdotcss');
```

Comment: what kind of permission i need to set? same code is working in my localserver. fontawesome and bootstrap can load from your way but how can i load other css and some custom js. current permission of all directories is 755

Comment: @ptailor Check out this link, there is written how to do it with filezilla http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/wordpress/navigation-customization/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-your-ftp-site/

Comment: sir i already asigned permission 755 but i am unable to access mytheme directory and directory name is Default.

Comment: did 777 but still facing same issue.